# How to share a song(mp3) in facebook using addthis script?

Tags: facebook, addthis

I have been using addthis script for social media sharing. Now I have to share a song in facebook. I have done so many searches and surfed a lot. I could not find the perfect solution  to share a song in facebook using addthis script.

Some posts said that need to keep a facebook appid to share. And some posts said do it simply and don't get complicated. But they does not show the way to reach a solution.

Please guide me to understand what things need to be done for sharing a song in facebook via addthis.

For information, I have tested the following codes to share a song.

```
<meta property='og:audio' content='song location path' />
<meta property='og:audio:title' content='title' />
<meta property='og:audio:artist' content='Artist name' />
<meta property='og:audio:type' content='application/mp3' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AddThis doesn't have any control over how your site is shared to Facebook. Your best bet for learning which Open Graph tags to use is to go to the official Open Graph Protocol site http://ogp.me/